# Error al ingresar un double con punto como separador de decimales

Tags: java

Si lo ingreso con coma (ej. 3,5), funciona bien.

```
package metodosnumericos;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class derivada {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //int coeficiente, potencia,x,xc,xp;
           Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
           double a;
           System.out.println("Ingresa");
         //  a=Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine());
           a=entrada.nextDouble();
           System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estimado `nextDouble()` usa los puntos decimales y separadores de miles propios del idioma.

En español el punto es separador de `miles` y la coma los `decimales`.

Prueba usando la funcion useLocale() y pasale un Locale inglés, de la siguiente manera:

```
entrada.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: hay otra manera de configurar eso, mi idioma es español peru

Comment: Tienes que elegir: o usas la configuración del español (y por tanto introduces comas como separador de decimales) o usas la configuración del inglés (y usas puntos como separador de decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera, remplazando Scanner por BufferedReader y obteniendo linea por linea.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Derivada {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));           
       double a = 0d;
       System.out.println("Ingresa un valor: ");
       a = Double.parseDouble(teclado.readLine());
       //Se interpreta que teclado.readLine(), obtiene el texto escrito hasta que se pulsa enter
       System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Verificalo, creo así debe de funcionar.